# How to use Jquery AJAX in spring boot Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I've newly started to look at how to use AJAX in my project. Is there any tutorial for Spring boot Controller using Jquery AJAX.

Most of the tutorials on the internet are using RestController, JSON as the example of Jquery AJAX.

Do I have to move my project from Controller to RestController? Can Thymeleaf achieve the same result as Jquery AJAX does?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, Ajax is used to send HTTP requests from the front-end to the back-end (Your Spring controllers).

```
     $.ajax({
      URL: "backEndServer/homePageController",
      type: "GET",
      success: function () {console.log("OK")},
    });
```

This sends a GET request to the controller at backEndServer/homePageController

```
@GetMapping(value = "/homePageController")
    public @ResponseBody String homePage() {
       // do things
    }
```

And finally, Thymeleaf is just a Java framework to generate HTML pages from templates and send them to the client.

I suggest you study the basics of Spring and Ajax more as you seem a bit lost.

Comment: `url` needs to be a string and solution doesn't show how to manage the response data

Comment: This is meant to be a rough demo of how it works since there is no code in the question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to be a repository of pseudo code rough demos. If the code will throw errors why post it? Beyond that the question is far too broad as outlined in the [help]